# mysql query count of duplicates and output format

Tags: mysql, sql

I've have this representation of my data where col1 is a recID (int), col2 is version (varchar), col3 is a patch (int).

There are duplicates in this table(rec 36,37):

```
recID  version  patch
32  5.1.4 434    -
36  5.1.4 434   p2
37  5.1.4 434   p2
```

I used this query to give me dups:

```
select recID,
 count(Version) as Count,
       Version
from Test
group by Version
having count > 1;
```

Output:

```
recID  Count  Version  Patch
32     3      434       -
```

How do I fix this query? I'd like to list the recIDs and this would be wrong since recID isn't a dup, but has a null value.

But what I'm looking for is to give me the versions that are dups and listing it this way (if possible)
Expected output:

```
recID  Count  Version  Patch 
32  1   5.1.4 434   -
36  2   5.1.4 434   p2
37  -   5.1.4 434   p2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get expected output using variables

```
select recID, version, patch, 
       case when @prevValue = version 
           then @cnt:=@cnt+1 
           else  @cnt:=0 
           end as DupCount, 
       @prevValue:=version as var_version 
FROM Table1, ( select @prevValue := NULL , @cnt:=0 ) t
order by version
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. My counts seem off. I'm getting a dup count of 2 for recID=37, 3 for recID=36, 4 for recID=34

Answer (score 0):

you can use below query, it will give the result you require..

```
    select t1.recID,t1.Version,t1.Patch,t2.cnt,
    case when exists(select * from #tmp where t1.recID > #tmp.recID and t1.Patch=#tmp.Patch and   t1.Version=#tmp.Version ) then 0 else t2.cnt end as cnt2
    from #tmp t1 inner join (
   select Version,Patch ,COUNT(recId) as cnt from #tmp
   group by Version,Patch)t2
    on t1.Patch=t2.Patch and t1.Version=t2.Version
```